# Slick Carousel smooth scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery, carousel, slick.js, smooth-scrolling

I have been using the slick carousel for a while, but I was curious if it was possible to tweak the carousel to get a smooth scrolling effect, as the same effect you get when you scroll vertically on your phone (on a given web page fx.).

In other words, I want the slick carousel to scroll in a variable speed, have a continuously flow, and will eventually not automatically head back to the start of a carousel/element, when you are not touching the carousel anymore.

Thanks

Comment: Related github request https://github.com/kenwheeler/slick/issues/1665

Answer (score 10):

For Smooth/Continous Scrolling

$('.continuous').slick({
speed: 9000,
autoplay: true,
autoplaySpeed: 0,
cssEase: 'linear',
slidesToShow: 1,
slidesToScroll: 1,
variableWidth: true,

});

Comment: Fiddle showing technique: https://jsfiddle.net/qu6cdbvt/

Answer (score 3):

As it says in the github-thread, I have linked in the comment to my question, the latest version of Slick does not support smooth scrolling.

I saw that Flickity and Swiper had good support for that, which I did some experiments with, but due to performance issues with both of them, I ended up making a simple horizontal div with multiple child-elements inside. That was the winning solution for me.

Source: 
https://codeburst.io/how-to-create-horizontal-scrolling-containers-d8069651e9c6

Cheers!